# Get the next rounded number of same scale

Tags: php, numbers

For instance I have the number `float(450250000)`, (~450 Million) I would need this number `int(500000000)` (500 Million).

Is there something PHP can do to determine this number no matter what is the scale of the number?

Comment: do you mean: if PHP can check number size and determine if it is convertable to int?

Comment: No. I just want that number. If it's `250` I want to find `300`.

Comment: You can apply the logic by counting the number of digits in a number. (I do not know if php offers in-built function for that)

Answer (score 2):

As Yash Mehta suggested you can do this:

```
function count_digit($number) {
    return strlen((string) $number);
}

$number = 256789;
$number_of_digits = count_digit($number);
echo round($number, - ($number_of_digits - 1));
```

this will output `30000`.

`round` is php function. You can find its documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php).

Comment: Glad that it helped! Cheers!

Comment: Hey, a quick update: this code will echo `700` for `720` but I would need it to get me `800`. So it might not be the right answer.

Comment: I updated the answer: `round($number, -($number_of_digits - 1) ) + round($number, -($number_of_digits) )/10` would return exactly what I need.

Comment: I don't think what you've wrote is a solution since it gives 900 for 750. You basically need round up function - for 601 -> 700, 3125 -> 4000 etc?